# Run Eclipse with given username and password

Tags: eclipse, command-prompt

I want to run Eclipse with given username and password. Instead of running it with default logged in Id/ as admin, I want to run it with some other username and pwd. How it can be done?

Comment: Huh?  What do you mean?  Eclipse has no "login..."  What OS?  You mean you want to start eclipse as a different OS user?

Comment: http://www.technipages.com/enable-right-click-run-as

Comment: I am running it on Windows and want to start it from command line with different userId other than the logged one user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start Eclipse through Shell Command [`runas`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.10).aspx).